# Filter on today's date in sharepoint list doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, date-time

I have a SharePoint list with gallery view. In that view I have set a filter.

In my column "Geboortedatum" I have set a date. But my filter which is set to "Geboortedatum" is equal to "[Today] doesn't work.

The column "Geboortedatum" is a type DATE/TIME column and is set to a long format.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: For me same scenario did work. Could you please share screen shot of the Geboortedatum column and view edit mode where you have configured filter?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried creating a new SharePoint list and list view based on `[Today]` filter on Date and Time column and it is working fine for me.

Here are the list view settings and all data (all items view) and filtered data (Today items view):

**All items view**:

[image]

**Today items view - Settings**:

[image]

**Today items view - Output**:

[image]

Same view in Gallery/Tiles format:

[image]

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/filter-on-today-s-date-in-sharepoint-list-doesn-t-work/m-p/3902961/highlight/false#M73822